# Neo4j Java APOC query

Tags: string, parsing, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I have my java app using Neo4j API. Everything works fine, except when I pass by args the path of my file to process.

This is the code working fine:

```
session.run("call 
apoc.xml.import(\"http://www.example.com/myfile.xml\") YIELD node
RETURN node");
```

Since I need to create an app which is general purpose, I need to pass the file from the user input. When I pass by args the URL, I got the error because there must be something wrong in the string.

This is the code with problem:

```
session.run("call apoc.xml.import(\" "  + file  + " \" ) YIELD node RETURN node");
```

where *file* is the variable containing http://www.example.com/myfile.xml

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the variable through the parameters:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put( "file", file );
session.run("call apoc.xml.import($file) YIELD node RETURN node", params);
```

[ https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.4/tutorials-java-embedded/#tutorials-cypher-parameters-java ]